# Faster Cell input values LibreOffice Vba

Tags: vba, libreoffice, cells, libreoffice-calc

I am trying to copy data (cca. 70*25*15 Cells) out of a txt file into libre office spreadsheet with a macro. Right now im accesing cells with this code :

```
Example:
Dim CellValue As Object

CellValue = ThisComponent.Sheets(1).getCellByPosition(i, j)
CellValue.String = "Whatever data i get from txt"
```

By running the above code and if text file have (70*25*15) cell entries, it needs 2min and 18 sec to copy all the data from text file to spreadsheet. Is there a better way to acess cells and speed up the process ?

Comment: Rather than getting the information on a cell by cell basis. Can you read in the whole range into an array and then process? Not 100% on LibreOffice but is what I would do in MS Excel

Comment: That is the problem ... in excell this would be really fast and easy but I need to use libre office for this specific task and it's way more complicated than it should be ....

Comment: Try to execute your code after you insert the line   ThisComponent.lockControllers before any action and   ThisComponent.unlockControllers after the end of all assignments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set the `DataArray` of an object which implements `XCellRangeData` form an array of arrays.

Example:

```
Sub Test()

  aDataArray = array(array("A1", "B1", "C1"), array("A2", 2.2, 2.3), array("A3", 3.2, 3.3))

  oDoc = ThisComponent

  oSheet = oDoc.getSheets().getByIndex(1)

  oRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByName("A1:C3")

  'xray oRange

  oRange.setDataArray(aDataArray)

End Sub
```

https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XCellRangeData.html#setDataArray

**Edit:**

More complex example:

```
Sub Test()

  lRowCount = 1800
  lColCount = 40

  dim aDataArray() as variant
  dim aColumnArray() as variant

  redim aDataArray(lRowCount-1) 'the main array is for rows; 0-based so count-1

  for lRow = lbound(aDataArray) to ubound(aDataArray)

   redim aColumnArray(lColCount-1) 'this array is for column data

   for lCol = lbound(aColumnArray) to ubound(aColumnArray)
    'create some sample data
    select case lCol
     case 1
      aColumnArray(lCol) = CInt(int((10 * rnd()) + 1) 'integer in column 2
     case 2
      aColumnArray(lCol) = CDbl(1000 * rnd()) 'double in column 3, later formatted as currency     
     case 3
      aColumnArray(lCol) = CDbl(date + int(365*rnd())) 'date in column 4, must be double in the array, will be later formatted as date
     case 4
      aColumnArray(lCol) = CInt(lRow mod 2 = 0) 'boolean in column 5, must be integer in the array, will be later formatted as booleann
     case else
      aColumnArray(lCol) = "r" & lRow & "c" & lCol 'all other columns string
    end select
   next
   aDataArray(lRow) = aColumnArray
  next

  oDoc = ThisComponent

  oSheet = oDoc.getSheets().getByIndex(0)

  lStartRow = 1
  lStartCol = 0
  'make sure, the size of the range will exactly match the array size
  oRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByPosition(lStartCol, lStartRow, lStartCol+lColCount-1, lStartRow+lRowCount-1)

  oRange.setDataArray(aDataArray) 'now the data is in the sheet

  'this code is for formatting
  oLocale = new com.sun.star.lang.Locale 'create empty locale

  oNumberFormats = thiscomponent.getNumberFormats() 'get NumberFormats from Calc

  'format column 3 as currency   
  oRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByPosition(2, lStartRow, 2, lStartRow+lRowCount-1)
  lCurrencyFormat = oNumberFormats.getStandardFormat(com.sun.star.util.NumberFormat.CURRENCY, oLocale)  
  oRange.NumberFormat = lCurrencyFormat

  'format column 4 as date
  oRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByPosition(3, lStartRow, 3, lStartRow+lRowCount-1)
  lFormat = oNumberFormats.getStandardFormat(com.sun.star.util.NumberFormat.DATE, oLocale)  
  oRange.NumberFormat = lFormat

  'format column 5 as boolean
  oRange = oSheet.getCellRangeByPosition(4, lStartRow, 4, lStartRow+lRowCount-1)
  lFormat = oNumberFormats.getStandardFormat(com.sun.star.util.NumberFormat.LOGICAL, oLocale)  
  oRange.NumberFormat = lFormat

End Sub
```

Comment: hey! Thanks for help, but i dont really understand what your solution is .... you would make an array of objects  and then just write into cells ? how would you acess the specific cell ?

Comment: My example writes an array of arrays with 9 elements into the range `A1:C3` (9 cells) of the second sheet of the active calc document. It does that in one step which is faster as doing it cell by cell.

Comment: Ohhhh ... i totaly misunderstood.  I get it now .... will try it out and report back :)

Comment: I made an array "Dim aDataArray(40,1800) As String" as this is the maximum size needed, i even tested the array by printing into cell the values one by one ... it took 5 minutes but it contained all the data when i try to run it your way it throws an exception com.star.una.Exception with meassage : .       *(only dot)

Comment: We have to use an array of arrays here, not a two dimensional array. What `Dim aDataArray(40,1800) As String` is supposed to be? 40 rows and 1800 columns? This this array would be in `Excel`.

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but I have never used these types. I have 40 columns and every collumn can have up to 1800 entries. This is what i have tryed now :  "Dim arr1(1800) As Variant" array with 1800 entries and then I wrote "aDataArray = array(40x arr1)" so now i have an array of arrays. But I get the same error, could you help me define the array of arrays or is there another problem with my approach ?

Comment: The first one should be `Dim arr1(40)` for the number of columns; the next one I believe should be `Dim aDataArray(1800)` for the number of rows and then combine one row at a time by setting one row's worth of values in arr1, then `aDataArray(0) = arr1()` and looping until you have all the rows.

Comment: @AxelRichter i worked trough your example, in my case I had to make a 2D array and insert the data then added your example and copied array of data into array in your example and the results are practically instant unlike the 2 minutes i needed before. Thanks a lot this is much more clear now.